# Contribution Page Confirmation Emails

Tags: civicontribute, email, contributions, confirmation

So, we recently set up a contribution page for people to buy tickets for a raffle we're hosting on our website. However, we are not receiving confirmation emails upon purchases. We get them when people donate through our "Donate Now" button but not for the raffle. Also, we have several fields on the contribution page that are not being displayed under the contributors profile. Can anyone help with this?

I hope this makes sense. I am new to United Way and CiviCRM so I'm rather in the dark with all of this. Hope someone can help!

Answer (score 2):

Can you check if you have turned on send receipt? You can check by navigation to CiviCRM >> Contributions >> Manage Contribution Pages

Click on Configure link besides the contribution page and then 'Thankyou and receipting'

Once you on receipt page scroll down and check the box 'Email Receipt to Contributor?' if its turned off.

Also check under 'Profiles' tab if you have included correct profile.

Comment: Sorry, let me rephrase this. When someone contributes, via our "Donate Now" button, our Director of Finance receives an email that someone made a purchase, and that email includes all the information provided in the fields. But we, the admins, are not receiving an email when someone purchases a raffle ticket on the Raffle's contribution page. We are having no trouble with sending receipts!

Comment: what is the difference between Donate now and Raffle's contribution page?

Comment: Raffle: https://www.unitedwaysm.org/civicrm/contribute/transact?reset=1&id=7

Comment: Donate: https://www.unitedwaysm.org/civicrm/contribute/transact?reset=1&id=1

Comment: If i understand correctly you dont receive a copy when someone purchases from id=7. So can you comfirm if contribution page id=7 has cc or bcc configured or is your site using any extension that is responsible to send email or any custom extension or code

Comment: Pls read Pradeep's original answer - he gave instructions on how to find via the UI if a CC or BCC has been (it is part of the 'Email Receipt to Contributor' section